# Как найти сумму цифр числа используя mod и div?

Tags: числа

Дано 4-х значное число. Найти сумму его цифр используя `mod` и `div`, дано 1000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот подсказка (осталось только сложение сделать), разбирайтесь:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int i = 6352;

    cout << i << "---->" << (i / 1000) % 10 << 
                     "-" << (i / 100) % 10 << 
                     "-" << (i / 10) % 10 << 
                     "-" << (i / 1) % 10 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```